# Named Pipes processing multiple messages

Tags: vb.net, named-pipes

I have a named pipes server running on a workstation. When the server receives a message I am able to process it. The problem is several messages can be sent at the same time. The server processes the first message but the remaining messages are lost. Not sure how to listen for multiple messages. I cannot batch the messages into one message as I need to have the server respond to each and every message separately. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this. My server code is below which is running in a thread.

```
    Dim Pipe As New Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("bellhop", Pipes.PipeDirection.InOut, -1, Pipes.PipeTransmissionMode.Message, Pipes.PipeOptions.Asynchronous)

    While BellhopExiting = False
        Pipe.WaitForConnection()

        Dim Reader As New StreamReader(Pipe)
        Dim XML As String = Reader.ReadLine

        If XML IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(Pipe)
            Writer.AutoFlush = True

            Try
                ParseXML(XML)

                'Send a success acknowledgement back to the sender.
                Writer.WriteLine("Message Delivered")

            Catch ex As Exception
                'Send a failed acknowledgement back to the sender.
                Writer.WriteLine("Failed->Bellhop->WaitForConnection->Computer: " & ComputerName & " Error: " & ex.Message)
            End Try

        End If

        Pipe.Disconnect()

    End While
```